# Assertion failure in reloading tableView with tableHeader TVOS

Tags: objective-c, uisearchcontroller, tvos

I am using `UISearchController` and I am getting this error after I try to reload data after filtering the content array. This doesn't happen if I set any other view than the tableView's `tableHeaderView` to be the searchBar of `UISearchController`. If I use any other view to hold the searchbar everything works fine. Has anyone had this error, if so what was the solution.

> Assertion failure in -[UITableView _cellReuseMapForType:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3512.29.300.16/UITableView.m:3962
>   2015-11-15 15:43:34.166 AirMediaCenterTV[23894:1052893] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to access view reuse map for unknown view type 4'

Comment: For what it's worth I ran into the same problem the last few days.    I had to remove the tableHeader completely to be able to reload the data.  I had a UISegmentedControl in my table header to do sorting and inside the header view it would crash with the above exception but moving it outside into the view controllers view fixed it.   If I have time I'm going to put together an example and file a bug report

Comment: @earthtrip yeah i had a similar workaround, just removed the search bar and put it elsewhere.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem on tvOS but I'm not using a UISearchController. For me, it started happening when I added a delay to my loadViewController to simulate loading data remotely (I'm currently using fake data now). Based on this, my guess is it has to do with thread access or some kind of race condition.

Comment: UPDATE: I discovered that I was getting this error because I had a button in the header of my tableview. When I disabled the button, I no longer got this error. The fix for me was to disable the button before reloading my table and then re-enable it after it was done loading. Definitely seems like a bug on Apple's part.

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a similar crash issue on tvOS but I can't seem to figure out a fix. I'm not using a `UISearchController`. I've removed all the `registerClass:` calls from the `UITableView` and that didn't seem to work.

Comment: This should be a comment.